# How to get params from <input> and redirect to another link with data

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Basically I Developed microservice on SpringBoot, that takes data from excel form and shows it as a table. I figured out how to do this, it works fine.

Now I used Elastic search that works fine when I send the request by my self. Now I need this to work on thymeleaf html.

Basically my page looks like this now

[image: My html ss]

What I need is, I input my search into search bar, and when I press the "Submit" button, it takes the searchRequest from search bar, redirects to the other link with the parameters the user entered before. Here is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Freight Masters LLC Agents</title>

    <style>
        /*** COLORS ***/
        /*** DEMO ***/
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #F4B942;
            font: 13px monospace;
            color: #232e57;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        .cntr {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .cntr .cntr-innr {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /*** STYLES ***/
        .search {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0px 8px 7px 0px;
            padding: 7px 9px 0px 9px;
            border: 3px solid #232e57;
            border-radius: 25px;
            transition: all 300ms ease;
            cursor: text;
        }
        .search:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 3px;
            height: 20px;
            right: -5px;
            top: 21px;
            background: #232e57;
            border-radius: 3px;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transition: all 300ms ease;
        }
        .search.active,
        .search:hover {
            width: 300px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .search.active:after,
        .search:hover:after {
            height: 0px;
        }
        .search input {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: inherit;
            background: transparent;
            outline-width: 0px;
        }

        .button {
            width: 180px;
            height: 45px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 2.5px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 45px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: #232e57;
            box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px #0f152b66;
            color: #fff;
            transform: translateY(-7px);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cntr">
        <div class="cntr-innr">
            <label style="margin-bottom: 32px" class="search" for="inpt_search">
                <input th:name="searchParams" id="inpt_search" type="text"/>
            </label><br>
            <button class="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $("#inpt_search").on('focus', function () {
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('active');
        });

        $("#inpt_search").on('blur', function () {
            if($(this).val().length == 0)
                $(this).parent('label').removeClass('active');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use something like the following.
As an aside, I would advice to wrap this into a `<form>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Freight Masters LLC Agents</title>

    <style>
        /*** COLORS ***/
        /*** DEMO ***/
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #F4B942;
            font: 13px monospace;
            color: #232e57;
        }
        p {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        .cntr {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .cntr .cntr-innr {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /*** STYLES ***/
        .search {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0px 8px 7px 0px;
            padding: 7px 9px 0px 9px;
            border: 3px solid #232e57;
            border-radius: 25px;
            transition: all 300ms ease;
            cursor: text;
        }
        .search:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 3px;
            height: 20px;
            right: -5px;
            top: 21px;
            background: #232e57;
            border-radius: 3px;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transition: all 300ms ease;
        }
        .search.active,
        .search:hover {
            width: 300px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .search.active:after,
        .search:hover:after {
            height: 0px;
        }
        .search input {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: inherit;
            background: transparent;
            outline-width: 0px;
        }

        .button {
            width: 180px;
            height: 45px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 2.5px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #000;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 45px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: none;
        }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: #232e57;
            box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px #0f152b66;
            color: #fff;
            transform: translateY(-7px);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cntr">
        <div class="cntr-innr">
            <label style="margin-bottom: 32px" class="search" for="inpt_search">
                <input th:name="searchParams" id="inpt_search" type="text"/>
            </label><br>
            <button class="button submit_search">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $("#inpt_search").on('focus', function () {
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('active');
        });

        $("#inpt_search").on('blur', function () {
            if($(this).val().length == 0)
                $(this).parent('label').removeClass('active');
        });
        
        /// On submit
        $(".submit_search").on('click', function () {
          var searchString = $("#inpt_search").val();
          /// Use searchString
          /// (example)
          window.open("https://www.example.com/?query="+ searchString);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would this solve the issue? Sure, a form element is easier to post data but it still requires a backend program to call different functions outside the website.

Comment: @tacoshy In the updated example I provided, Kamal can use the input as he likes. He says: "[...] when I press the "Submit" button, it takes the searchRequest from search bar, redirects to the other link with the parameters the user entered before."

Comment: @tacoshy And I recommended the <form> element, because of .on('submit') and possibly validation.

Comment: @Savado, sorry, I dont see any <form> in my edited html. I Only see the update js script.

Comment: @KamalMuradov Yes, the mention of the <form> element was just an aside. If you wrap your form element in a <form>, you can use .on('submit'). But you can use the 'searchString' on submit, to redirect the user to a link. I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay, everything works fine, Thanks!